# Why is portalcontent not injected?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to get my head around react portals so I created a portal root for header content in my component called MasterLayout:

```
<div
    ref={portalRoot => {
    this.portalRoot = portalRoot;
 }}
/>
```

In this component it throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

     componentDidMount() {
      26 |   debugger
    > 27 |   this.portalRoot.appendChild(this.container);
         | ^  28 | }
```

Trying to inject content into this portalRoot from another component called FlexStuff:

```
 const PortalContent = (
      <SearchWidgetWrapper>
        <SearchWidgetContent justify="flex-end" mx="auto">
          <SearchContainer>
           <Box>portalcontent</Box>
          </SearchContainer>
        </SearchWidgetContent>
      </SearchWidgetWrapper>
    );

 return [
      <Box p={24} flex="1 0 auto" column>
              this is FlexStuff
      </Box>,
      ReactDOM.createPortal(PortalContent, HEADER_CONTAINER),
 ];
```

Why do I get this error? How can I inject the FlexStuff content? [Link to github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/portal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the Header component is not rendering children passed via props, so `portalRoot` div never gets mounted and the ref stays undefined.

To fix it change the Header component to render the children:

```
export class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```